# Does MySQL treat Varchars as absolute values?

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have a table where one of the columns is data type varchar. Here are some of the values:

```
-.001
-.010
-7.13
```

When I sort descending, it gives me this:

```
-7.13
-.010
-.01
```

This is backwards, but correct if you take the absolute values of the numbers. Similarly, if I run a query for the max of these numbers, it gives me -7.13.

Is that what MySQL does for varchar?

(P.S. I am using Sequel Pro on a Mac, which sometimes has some funny settings. Could that be the reason?)

Answer (score 2):

No.  Varchars are sorted in alphabetical order, which would (for single characters) correspond to ASCII encoding.  In the ASCII encoding (see [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)), a period is "46" which is less than 0, which is "48".

In other words, your values are just sorted in the order that their characters say they should be.

If you want a numeric sort, then you can use `+ 0` to do silent conversion to a number ("silent" means that errors are ignored).  That is:

```
order by col + 0 desc
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I do a case when statement where I say: "case when a < -.78" will it really give me the correct values? Or will it give me values like 0 also?

Comment: MySQL will process the statement correctly.  Whether it does what you want depends on your expectations.  MySQL will convert a string to a number in a context where it expects a number.  In this context, `a` would be converted to a number if it is not already a number.